# How to resolve a plugin error message on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How can I solve ajax error message from slider revolution
I tried to make some changes on a webpage, but the plugin used is refusing to come up
I tried updating the plugin, but I'm unable to do so.
I will really need help to sort this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Slider Revolution premium plugin?
If it's a nulled one, you won't be able to update. All you have to do is get the premium version of the plugin.